# How to explain weird characters at the end of my char array, and the wrong result of using strlen function in my code

Tags: c++

I am a complete beginner so the code may seem to be easy, but I cannot find a solution why it returns such values as:

input: kkkk

output:
14
kkkkřřřř╩┬ëŢ

Suprisingly the code works fine with online compilators, but not with the Visual Studio.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
char word[20];
std::cin >> word;

int length = strlen(word);
int p = length - 1, i = 0;
char *var=new char [length];

while (i < length&&p>=0)
{
    var[i]= word[p];
        p--;
        i++;
}
std::cout <<strlen(var)<<endl<< var;
if (!strcmp(var, word)) std::cout << "\nThe word is a palindrome";

    return 0;
}
```

I can not use strings because my University doesn't allow to do so. I also know there are many different ways to attend to this problem but I just really want know what I have done wrong in this one :/

Comment: Whats `sprawdzenie`?

Comment: You forgot the fundamental property of all C-style char strings, which are always terminated by a 0 byte. The shown code fails to append the '\0' byte.

Comment: Hint -- C-style strings are null-terminated, and certain functions are looking for that null.  You're missing this.

Comment: Can you explain how are you expecting `strlen(var)` to work? What information do you expect it to look at to determine the length of the string?

Answer (score 2):

Your "copy routine" copies each character, but it does not copy the string termination character. Note that C-style strings as used in functions like `strlen` or `strcmp` need to be 0-terminated, and even `cout <<`, when getting a  parameter of type `char*`, treats this as a C-style string: It will read until finding the terminating `'\0'`, and if you do not write one, it will read beyond the boundaries you think it should do.

If your write

```
...
}
var[length] = '\0';
std::cout <<strlen(var)<<endl;
...
```

it should work.